# The union is not disjoint in the example from the book

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I am reading 'Measure, Integral and Probability' book. There is this following para in the book:

> An equivalence relation $\sim$ on $E$ partitions $E$ into disjoint
>    equivalence classes: given $x \in E$, write $[x] = \{z : z \sim x\}$
>    for the equivalence class of $x$, i.e. the set of all elements of $E$
>    that are equivalent to $x$. Thus $x \in [x]$, hence $E = \cup_{x \in
>  E} [x]$. **This is a disjoint** union: if $[x] \cap [y] \neq
>  \emptyset$, then there is $z \in E$ with $x \sim z$ and $z \sim y$,
>    hence $x \sim y$, so that $[x] = [y]$. We shall denote the set of all
>   equivalence classes so obtained by $E/\sim$.

First of all, I do not see how $ \cup_{x \in E} [x]$ is a disjoint union. Take, for example, a set

$$S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$$ with the following equivalence on it:

$$\sim = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(1,3),(3,1) \}$$

then

$[1] = \{1,2,3\}$, $[2]=\{1,2,3\}$, $[3]=\{1,2,3\}$, $[4]=\{4\}$, $[5]=\{5\}$. Already, you have that sert $[1]$ is the same as $[2]$. So that the union $\cup_{x \in E} [x] = \{1,2,3\} \cup \{1,2,3\}$ and that's not disjoint. Unless I do not understand what disjoint union means.

Also, what is $E/\sim$?

Comment: It should probably say take distinct representatives for each equivalence class, then that would be a disjoint union.

Comment: what about $E/\sim$ is that just $\cup_{x \in E} [x]$?

Comment: No it would just consist of the representatives for each equivalence class. That is, $E / \sim = \{ [x] \ | \ x \in E \}$. In your example, $E/ \sim = \{ [1] , \ [4], \ [5] \}$. Of course you could use $[2]$ and $[3]$ for representatives of the class of $[1]$ instead, but they are the same under the relation $\sim$.