# Do I have errata in my measure book: Measure, Integral and Probability II by Capinski

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The author goes to define what equivalence (from basic set theory) means on page 4. This book can be found online. But here is a short summary:

Given any set $E$, an equivalence relation on $E$ is a relation (i.e. a subset $R$ of $E \times E$, where we write $x \sim y$ to indicate that $(x,y) \in R$) with the following properties:

1. reflexive: $\forall x \in E$, $x \sim x$
2. symmetric: $x \sim y \implies y \sim x$
3. transitive: $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$ implies $x \sim z$

An equivalence class for $x \in E$ is then defined as $[x] = \{z: z \sim x\}$. An equivalence relation partiions $E$ into disjoin equivalence classes. It is also obvious that $x \in [x]$ and thus $E = \cup_{x \in E}[x]$. But author proceeds to state that this union is disjoin if (**all of the following I do not understand**):

if $[x] \cap [y] \neq \emptyset$

(but by definition of disjoin union we actually want the intersections to be empty; so I though that this was a typo, and it should be $= \emptyset$; but I have not yet thought about this in perspective on the structure that we have defined above, and maybe that actually does not make sense; Now I have thought about it, if there is $E = \{1, 2\}$ and $R = \{(1,1), (2,2), (1,2), (2,1)\}$ then $[1] \cap [2]$ is not empty, they are the same.)

then there is $z \in E$ with $x \sim z$ and $z \sim y$, hence $x \sim y$ so that $[x] = [y]$.

So yeah... We have above that $[1] = \{1,2\} = [2]$ but the union $[1] \cup [2]$ is not disjoint... Or is my disjoint definition incorrect.

I had dejavu writing this, apparently I already [asked this before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038634/the-union-is-not-disjoint-in-the-example-from-the-book) but did not get an answer.

Comment: Not very clear... An equivalence relation $R$ on a set $E$ partitions the set $E$ into *disjoint* [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class). This for sure...

Comment: I think that the issue is that if $x,y \in E$ and $x \sim y$, then in $\bigcup_{x \in E} [x]$ we consider many "copies" of each equiv classes. I.e. for $x,y$ as above we have $[x]$ and $[y]$. The condition of being an equiv rel is exactly : $x \sim y \text { iff } [x]=[y] \text { iff } [x] \cap [y] \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: This means that if $x \sim y$ then $[x]=[y]$. Thus, in your example : $[1]=[2]$ that means (recall *Extensionality*) that the quotient set $E/\sim$ has only one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand what the author is saying. They are not saying it's a disjoint union because $[x]\cap [y]\neq \emptyset$. They're saying it's a disjoint union because **if** $[x]\cap [y] \neq \emptyset$, then $[x]=[y]$. In other words, no two different equivalence classes can overlap.

For instance, let $E=\mathbb{N}$, and $R=\{(x,y) \mid x,y\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } 3 \text{ divides } (x-y)\}$. We can write 
$$\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{N}} [x] = [0]\cup [1]\cup [2]\cup [3] \cup \cdots.$$ How is this union disjoint? Notice that $[0]=[3]=[6]=\cdots$, and similarly $[1]=[4]=[7]=\cdots$, and $[2]=[5]=[8]=\cdots$. So this union is really
$$\mathbb{N}=[0]\cup [1]\cup [2]$$
which *is* disjoint.

Comment: So much happy!! I have answer)) I will check it out later! Thank you

Comment: I do not follow, sorry. If natural numbers include zero then $R = \{(3,0), (6,0), (6,3), (9,0), (9, 3), ... \}$ also by symmetry implies that $\{(0,3), (0,6), (3, 6), ...\} \subset R$, but $0-3=-3$ is not a nautal number. What is your definition of divides? i.e. there is no remainder? If natural numbers do not include zero, then would $[0] = \emptyset$? Ahh.. The difference does not have to be in $E$

Comment: I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is exactly what the author writes then there would be some clarification helpful.

Often one chooses a so called system $\Sigma \subset E$ of representatives from each equivalence class as follows:

- For each $x \in E$ there is a $\sigma \in \Sigma$ s.t. $[x] = [\sigma]$
- If $x,y \in \Sigma$ and $x \neq y \Rightarrow [x] \neq [y]$, hence $[x] \cap [y] = \emptyset$

Then we can write

$$E = \bigcup_{\sigma \in \Sigma}[\sigma]$$
where the union is disjoint.

Note, that one needs the axiom of choice to assure the existence of such a system of representatives in general.